# Vue, using operator on data array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an events object that I'm dumping into the console right now, which consists of the id, date, category and then an array of notifications (each item in the array has notification_type and notification_message)

It looks like this in console:

```
0:
  iD: 123
  date: "2020/03/03"
  category: "New"
  notifications: Array(2)
    0:
      notification_type: "new notification"
      notification_message: "teting notifications"
    1:
      notification_type: "internal notification"
      notification_message: "teting internal"
```

So I have my vue for loop on the main events object, which works fine except I can't figure out how to get the comment on there. Basically, I want this to only show the message for the new notification type:

```
        <tr v-for="event in events">
          <td>{{ event.id }}</td>
          <td>{{event.date}}</td>
          <td>{{event.category}}</td>
          <td v-if="event.notifications.notification_type === 'new notification'">{{event.notifications.notification_message}}</td>
        </tr>
```

This still loads everything but the notification, which isn't loaded at all.

How can I change this to get only the 'new notification' value on this table data cell?

Comment: N is this a typo `event.notifications.notification_type` instead of `event.Notifications.notification_type`?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik I just fixed it, I accidentally capitalized the array name here, but it's actually lowercase

Comment: Also, if the key `Category: "New"` can be used to check new notification?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik no, the category has to do with product (New, Used, resale, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `event.notifications` notification is an array, which means you cannot access the property inside the object of each element inside array. It will be `undefined`.

In this case, your are checking

```
undefined === 'new notification' // false
```

If you always want to access the first element, then simply 
`event.notifications[0].notification_type`. Otherwise, you need to loop over the internal array using `v-for`.

Comment: how how can I access the array in my initial v-for loop then?

Answer (score 0):

```
Just change your vue code like below :
Here event['notifications'] is an array so it needs to be handled:

       <tr v-for="event in events">
          <td>{{ event.id }}</td>
          <td>{{event.date}}</td>
          <td>{{event.category}}</td>
          <td v-for="notification in event['notifications']" v-if="notification['notification_type'] == 'new notification'">{{notification.notification_message}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td v-if="event.notifications.notification_type === 'new notification'">
```

If your event.notifications is an array then you won't be able to access it like this, so I think thath's where your problem is coming from. You might want to add another for in here. Something like this should work:

```
<td v-for="notif in event.notifications" v-if="notif.notification_type === 'new notification'">{{notif.notification_message}}</td>
```